# How to seq_along() two lists with a for loop

Tags: r, list, loops, iteration

I have a function that needs to iterate two list inputs.

```
date <- as.list("JANUARY", "FEBRUARY")
type <- as.list("Education", "Government")
```

The function being something like `clean(date, type)`

So this is the code I've attempted using:

```
for(i in (seq_along(date), seq_along(type)) {
  a <- date[i]
  b <- type[i]
  clean(a, b)
}
```

But it's not iterating each list item against each other, but rather the position of the list with the respective position of the other list. So the output looks is the cleaning results for

JANUARY:Education, FEBRUARY:Government, JANUARY:Education, FEBURARY:Government

When I want it to have the combination of

JANUARY:Education, JANUARY:Government, FEBRUARY:Education, FEBRUARY:Government

I hope this make sense and if anyone could help I would really appreciate it.

Comment: `as.list("JANUARY", "FEBRUARY")` is wrong, it's just generating `"JANUARY"`. Perhaps you mean `list`? That doesn't resolve your question, but it's still wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First problem: `as.list` works only on the first argument, so your `date` is coming up as `"JANUARY"`. To resolve this, use `dat <- list(...)` instead.

```r
as.list(1,2,3)
# [[1]]
# [1] 1
list(1,2,3)
# [[1]]
# [1] 1
# [[2]]
# [1] 2
# [[3]]
# [1] 3
```

Second, this is something like an "outer join", in that you want each of the first vector paired with each of the second vector. The `outer` function does something like this, with two properties:

1. Its return value is a `matrix`, which is not always what is needed. See `outer(1:3, 4:5,`*`)` to see what this looks like.
2. It comes up with an expansion and calls the function *once*, so we can see what things look like here:

   ```r
   outer(1:3, 4:5, function(a, b) { browser(); a*b; })
   # Called from: FUN(X, Y, ...)
   debug at #1: a * b
   a
   # [1] 1 2 3 1 2 3
   b
   # [1] 4 4 4 5 5 5
   ```

   It might be easier to see the pairs this way:

   ```r
   cbind(a,b)
   #      a b
   # [1,] 1 4
   # [2,] 2 4
   # [3,] 3 4
   # [4,] 1 5
   # [5,] 2 5
   # [6,] 3 5
   ```

   So our operation needs to be able to deal with all data at once.

   ```r
   a*b
   # [1]  4  8 12  5 10 15
   ```

   Often, the function (your `clean`) needs a singleton in each argument, so `outer` doesn't always work well.

An alternative is to use `expand.grid`.

```r
eg <- expand.grid(date = date, type = type, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
eg
#       date       type
# 1  JANUARY  Education
# 2 FEBRUARY  Education
# 3  JANUARY Government
# 4 FEBRUARY Government
```

From here, there are a few approaches, depending on your proficiency and preferences towards elegance. `mapply` is similar to `sapply` in that it tries to return a simplified structure, but it accepts a function an an arbitrary number of vectors/lists:

```r
mapply(function(a, b) paste(a, b, sep = ","), eg$date, eg$type)
# [1] "JANUARY,Education"   "FEBRUARY,Education"  "JANUARY,Government"  "FEBRUARY,Government"
```

or `Map`, the variant that *always* returns a `list` (this is my preference, since I like to *know* what is being returned):

```r
Map(function(a, b) paste(a, b, sep = ","), eg$date, eg$type)
# [[1]]
# [1] "JANUARY,Education"
# [[2]]
# [1] "FEBRUARY,Education"
# [[3]]
# [1] "JANUARY,Government"
# [[4]]
# [1] "FEBRUARY,Government"
```

In your case, this might be just `out <- Map(clean, eg$date, eg$type)`.

Some people prefer `for` loops, though, and so the equivalent is something like:

```r
for (i in seq_len(nrow(eg))) {
  print(paste(eg$date[i], eg$type[i], sep = ","))
}
# [1] "JANUARY,Education"
# [1] "FEBRUARY,Education"
# [1] "JANUARY,Government"
# [1] "FEBRUARY,Government"

### your equivalent:
for (i in seq_len(nrow(eg))) {
  clean(eg$date[i], eg$type[i])
}
```

To see how `Map` (and `mapply`) operates, it might be helpful to "unroll" what  is going on. If I do `Map(paste, eg$date, eg$type)` (and the lists are longer, say length `n`), then it effectively does

```r
paste(eg$date[1], eg$type[1])
paste(eg$date[2], eg$type[2])
...
paste(eg$date[n], eg$type[n])
```

and wraps each return value into a `list` (for `Map`) or `vector` (for `mapply`, if the data is all the same type/shape/length/dim/...).

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer - it really helped me understand the gaps I was missing while writing this code. It worked and I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using `for` loops if you really want to use one:

```
date <- list("JANUARY", "FEBRUARY")
type <- list("Education", "Government") 

clean <- function (a, b){
  c <- list()
  k <- 1
for (i in seq_along(a)) {
  for (j in seq_along(b)) {
    c[k] <- paste(a[[i]],b[[j]],sep=",")
    k <- k+1
  }
}
  return(c)
}
```

> Output

```
> clean(date,type)
[[1]]
[1] "JANUARY,Education"

[[2]]
[1] "JANUARY,Government"

[[3]]
[1] "FEBRUARY,Education"

[[4]]
[1] "FEBRUARY,Government"
```