# R: Delete rows where one column is a substring of another

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
c1      c2
fish    fishing
dog     tomato
cat     loop
horse   horse
```

I would now like to delete every row where c1 == c2 AND where c1 is a substring of c2 and vice versa. In my example, horse == horse and 'fish' is a substring of 'fishing'. I know about the grepl function, e.g.: `df[!grepl(df$c1, df$c2),]`.

However, this solution does not account for substrings. Maybe there is a solution where I can use `df[!grepl("STRING", df$c2),]` for every row, so that "STRING" equals the value of df$c1?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### base R

```r
dat[!with(dat, mapply(grepl, c1, c2)) & !with(dat, mapply(grepl, c2, c1)),]
#    c1     c2
# 2 dog tomato
# 3 cat   loop
```

`grepl` only works on one pattern at a time: if you try multiple patterns (i.e., each of `dat$c1`), then you'll receive a warning (and not the intended output).

```r
grepl(dat$c1, dat$c2)
# Warning in grepl(dat$c1, dat$c2) :
#   argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

We vectorize it (with `mapply`) and run it iteratively on each of the `c1`/`c2` pairs.

Comment: A much interesting and difficult question would be how to do it if you have many columns. The combinations for either grepl or str_detect would grow exponentially...

Comment: "Everything" is better if it can scale elegantly to *"one or more"* or *"zero or more"*. However, there's nothing in the OP that suggests it is more than exactly two columns, am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I might ask a new question for a more general approach

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for! Now I better understand what mapply is useful for. Unfortunately, I can't upvote answers yet.

Comment: I have a good link or two explaining `mapply` but I'm not on my computer, I'll find them later. In the meantime, whether or not you can upvote (I think you can now), you should always *accept* the answer that best resolves your question: find the checkmark to the left of the answer you prefer and click it. You can accept at most one, and your can upvote all or none or anything in between. Thanks!

Comment: @diggi2395, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60998496/3358272) is a previous answer of mine that walks through `mapply`/`Map` (almost identical). If you understand `lapply` (perform a function on each element of a list), then think of `Map` (`lapply`) or `mapply` (`sapply`) as running a function on a "zipped-together" combination of multiple lists. Hope these help.

Answer (score 2):

Using `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
        filter(!str_detect(c2, c1), !str_detect(c1, c2))
```

Output:

```
    c1     c2
1: dog tomato
2: cat   loop
```

This will work no matter which columns have similar words (not just like in your specific example).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Unfortunately, I can't upvote answers yet.